# Issue running an ansible playbook in WSL2/Ubuntu that runs fine in MacOS

Tags: visual-studio-code, ansible, yaml, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have a *tcpdump.yaml* file that I and the rest of my team are able to run just fine in a terminal in VSCode (and Atom) on Mac, but when I try to run the same playbook on my Windows laptop, I get several fatal errors related to variable. This playbook runs without error on the other machines for our team, and I am waiting for my Mac to come in, but I would like to get this working in the mean time.

> fatal: [sample-dev-04]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ tcpdump.stdout_lines | regex_search('10.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+') }}): expected string or bytes-like object"}

> fatal: [sample-dev-04]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'tcpdump_switch' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/testuser/.ansible/testcode/Playbooks/tcpdump.yaml': line 21, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Print tcpdump relevant information\n  ^ here\n"}

Here is the code in question. The first 3 tasks run without error; problems start with the `Set_fact variables` and `Print tcpdump relevant information` tasks (errors above respectively). I also get the same second error above in the resultant *phpipam_tcpdump.yaml*.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL2 in Windows 10 21.04, GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1).

```yaml
---

- name: Set default_mac
  set_fact:
    default_mac: "{{ ansible_facts.default_ipv4.macaddress }}"

- name: Set default_interface
  set_fact:
    default_interface: "{{ ansible_facts.default_ipv4.interface }}"

- name: Run tcpdump on default network interface
  command: tcpdump -nn -v -i "{{ default_interface }}" -s 1500 -c 1 'ether[20:2] == 0x2000'
  register: tcpdump

- name: Set_fact variables
  set_fact:
    tcpdump_switch: "{{ tcpdump.stdout_lines | regex_search('10.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+') }}"
    tcpdump_port: "{{ tcpdump.stdout_lines | regex_search('GigabitEthernet+[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+') }}"
    tcpdump_vlan: "{{ tcpdump.stdout_lines | regex_search('bytes: [0-9]+') | regex_replace('bytes: ') }}"

- name: Print tcpdump relevant information
  no_log: false
  debug:
    msg:
      - "MAC: {{ default_mac }}"
      - "Nework interface: {{ default_interface }}"
      - "Switch IP: {{ tcpdump_switch }}"
      - "Port: {{ tcpdump_port }}"
      - "Vlan: {{ tcpdump_vlan }}"

- name: Include phpipam_tcpdump.yaml
  include: ./phpipam_tcpdump.yaml
```

Comment: You have some check on your's register vars ? if not make a task with debug; msg : "{{ tcpdump }}"

Comment: Deleted my answer since it's obviously not relevant in your case based on your comment.  I'll keep thinking about it, though.

Comment: If you debug the value of the `tcpdump` variable after the `Run tcpdump on default network interface`, what does it look like? Does it have the expected content?

Comment: Probably you have a different version of Ansible in there than the other, have you confirmed that? I would recommend to install via [`pip`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-and-upgrading-ansible-with-pip) rather than via the packet manager of the OS/distrib. Another possibility is that you have an issue with carriage returns ([`\n` on Linux; `\r` on Mac, `\r\n` on Windows](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mac-os-x/0596004605/ch01s06.html)) in the file _tcpdump.yaml_.